# I have successfully created obj, mtl and texture image file but not able to generate 3D image using them

Tags: python, 3d, wavefront, face, pywavefront

I have successfully created .obj, .mtl and .png texture file for 3D face reconstruction using this [repository](https://github.com/YadiraF/PRNet). In this obj file, I have v, vt, and f, and I have successfully plotted the obj file, but it doesn't work when it comes to using all these files to generate a 3D image. Source code to generate a 3D image using these files is attached below. I have tested other already generate files to reconstruct a 3D image using this code it works fine.

```
import os
import pygame
from OpenGL.GL import *


class OBJ:
    generate_on_init = True
    @classmethod
    def loadTexture(cls, imagefile):
        surf = pygame.image.load(imagefile)
        image = pygame.image.tostring(surf, 'RGBA', 1)
        ix, iy = surf.get_rect().size
        texid = glGenTextures(1)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image)
        return texid

    @classmethod
    def loadMaterial(cls, filename):
        contents = {}
        mtl = None
        dirname = os.path.dirname(filename)

        for line in open(filename, "r"):
            if line.startswith('#'): continue
            values = line.split()
            if not values: continue
            if values[0] == 'newmtl':
                mtl = contents[values[1]] = {}
            elif mtl is None:
                raise ValueError("mtl file doesn't start with newmtl stmt")
            elif values[0] == 'map_Kd':
                # load the texture referred to by this declaration
                mtl[values[0]] = values[1]
                imagefile = os.path.join(dirname, mtl['map_Kd'])
                mtl['texture_Kd'] = cls.loadTexture(imagefile)
            else:
                mtl[values[0]] = list(map(float, values[1:]))
        return contents

    def __init__(self, filename, swapyz=False):
        """Loads a Wavefront OBJ file. """
        self.vertices = []
        self.normals = []
        self.texcoords = []
        self.faces = []
        self.gl_list = 0
        dirname = os.path.dirname(filename)

        material = None
        for line in open(filename, "r"):
            if line.startswith('#'): continue
            values = line.split()
            if not values: continue
            if values[0] == 'v':
                v = list(map(float, values[1:4]))
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
                self.vertices.append(v)
            elif values[0] == 'vn':
                v = list(map(float, values[1:4]))
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
                self.normals.append(v)
            elif values[0] == 'vt':
                self.texcoords.append(list(map(float, values[1:3])))
            elif values[0] in ('usemtl', 'usemat'):
                material = values[1]
            elif values[0] == 'mtllib':
                self.mtl = self.loadMaterial(os.path.join(dirname, values[1]))
            elif values[0] == 'f':
                face = []
                texcoords = []
                norms = []
                for v in values[1:]:
                    w = v.split('/')
                    face.append(int(w[0]))
                    if len(w) >= 2 and len(w[1]) > 0:
                        texcoords.append(int(w[1]))
                    else:
                        texcoords.append(0)
                    if len(w) >= 3 and len(w[2]) > 0:
                        norms.append(int(w[2]))
                    else:
                        norms.append(0)
                self.faces.append((face, norms, texcoords, material))
        if self.generate_on_init:
            self.generate()

    def generate(self):
        self.gl_list = glGenLists(1)
        glNewList(self.gl_list, GL_COMPILE)
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glFrontFace(GL_CCW)
        for face in self.faces:
            vertices, normals, texture_coords, material = face

            mtl = self.mtl[material]
            if 'texture_Kd' in mtl:
                # use diffuse texmap
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mtl['texture_Kd'])
            else:
                # just use diffuse colour
                glColor(*mtl['Kd'])

            glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
            for i in range(len(vertices)):
                if normals[i] > 0:
                    glNormal3fv(self.normals[normals[i] - 1])
                if texture_coords[i] > 0:
                    glTexCoord2fv(self.texcoords[texture_coords[i] - 1])
                glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertices[i] - 1])
            glEnd()
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEndList()

    def render(self):
        glCallList(self.gl_list)

    def free(self):
        glDeleteLists([self.gl_list])
```

Comment: Please specify what exactly doesn't work. Did you get an error or unexpected results? Provide as much context and inputs as necessary and as little code as possible to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I am not able to view the OBJ file with texture as I have used multiple software and codes for viewing obj file with texture. I think there is some issue with the code as I have used some prebuilt obj objects with texture image(s)-from pywavefront- and was able to successfully view it. Link to the source code (repository) is given and I am not able to figure out the issue.